# Python - os.walk won't copy files from multiple folders

Tags: python

I have this script that hopefully moves all the files in multiple folders into a new folder. I used the `os.walk` and `shtil.copy` functions. However the script does not work.

Here is the script:

```
import os
import shutil


for root, dirs, filename in os.walk(r"C:\Users\edward\OneDrive\Suspensia Pictures"):
    MoveFrom = r"C:\Users\edward\OneDrive\Suspensia Pictures"
    MoveTo = r"C:\Users\edward\OneDrive\Pics"
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(MoveFrom, filename), os.path.join(MoveTo, filename))
```

Here is the error I get:

```
TypeError: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'list'
```

Comment: `filename` is a *list* of files in `root`, not a single file name.

Comment: should I change it to file then as well in the shutil.copy kine too?

Comment: You have to iterate over the list of files and copy them separately. (Or use something capable of moving a set of files to a destination directory.)

Comment: would you hvae any idea on how to do that

Comment: Note that `os.walk()` descends into subdirectories, so hard-coding your `MoveFrom` will also lead to an error if the file is in a subdirectory.  Use the `root` arg from your iteration over `os.walk()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import shutil
from pathlib import Path


for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r"C:\Users\edward\OneDrive\Suspensia Pictures"):
    MoveFrom = r"C:\Users\edward\OneDrive\Suspensia Pictures"
    MoveTo = r"C:\Users\edward\OneDrive\Pics"

    for name in files:
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(path, name), Path(MoveTo))
```

Comment: I get an error `shutil.SameFileError:`

Answer (score 0):

As the [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) documentation said,

> filenames is a list of the names of the non-directory files in dirpath.
> which means that the `filename` in your code is type of `list` and that is not acceptable type for `join()`.

Here's a possible way to solve it,

```py
import os
import shutil


files: list
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"."):
    source_path = r"."
    target_path = r"../test"
    for file in files:
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(source_path)):
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(source_path, file), os.path.join(target_path, file))
```

One thing that you should consider is that the files from the result of `os.walk` would be the files in each folder under the root, which is recursive. So, this script only is able to handle the files in the depth 1.

For moving all the files in each of the folder under your specific directory, this script may work.

```py
import os
import shutil


files: list
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"."):
    target_path = r"../test"
    for file in files:
        source_path = os.path.join(root, file)
        shutil.copy(source_path, os.path.join(target_path, file))
```